# What causes dark patches in stained wood?

Tags: staining

I'm having trouble with staining wood correctly and I'm getting dark patches as seen in the picture below:

[image]

**Materials:**

1. Bare new radiata pine
2. Stain timber primer
3. Oak Stain w/ 50% reducer

**My process used:**

1. Orbital sander with 80 grit to smooth out gaps between panels (spot sanding, but also in other areas apart from the patches)
2. Orbital sanding with 180 grit along the entire board
3. Wipe down with spirits
4. Apply Timber Primer with bristle brush
5. Wait 12h+ as in instructions
6. Apply stain with bristle brush horizontally, panel by panel
7. Wait 2 minutes
8. Wipe excess down with a rag

In retrospect, the instructions of the primer said apply a flood coat. While I was liberal in some areas, I might not have been everywhere. Would this be the main reason?

Comment: Are you aware of blotching in softwoods and a few hardwood species? This is certainly going to be part of the issue and even at best you can't expect radiata to stain well, but this is particularly severe. The irregular application of "timber primer" (whatever that is) aside I have a suspicion it actually indicates the wood's surface was degraded somewhat (e.g. caused by poor storage at point of sale, unfortunately all too common).

Comment: I believe timber primer is the same as wood preconditioner - http://www.feastwatson.com.au/consumer/products/interior/product-details/1178